# Angular child state causing url change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have these states defined (after defining an abstract state `site`):

```
            .state('catalog', {
                parent: 'site',
                url: '/catalog?salesorg',
                template: '<catalog></catalog>'
            })
            .state('product', {
                parent: 'catalog',
                url: '/product/:id',
                template: '<product-details></product-details>'
            })
```

I try to go to the `product` state with this:

```
$state.go('product', { id: materialNumber });
```

Which is fired by:

```
<a ng-click="vm.goToProductDetails(product.materialNumber)">Product</a>
```

The page does not change though the URL does:

```
/#/catalog/product/000000000000123805
```

I am trying to make the `product` state a child of `catalog` state so that it can inherit the scope of `catalog`, but I don't want to have the URL include `/catalog` before `/product` as that would break the current URL scheme.

Comment: would be the param passed must be by different form, becose the first object after name, is stateParams. Cold Be?

Comment: can you please add some HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we should adjust:

- the catalog state, to has an target for its child
- the product state url definition, to skip parent part

an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/eyhvFuemn4hlo9qQQiiu?p=preview)

```
    .state('catalog', {
      parent: 'site',
      url: '/catalog?salesorg',
      template: '<catalog></catalog><div ui-view="" ></div>'
    })
    .state('product', {
      parent: 'catalog',
      url: '^/product/:id',
      template: '<product-details></product-details>'
    })
```

Check complete stuff [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/eyhvFuemn4hlo9qQQiiu?p=preview)